# Insert array into relational-database only work with data in the array that already exist in the database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, relational-database

**EDIT:** *The problem was solved within the foreach loop. Since the foreach loop only said that new ingredients should be inserted into the ingredient database it didn't say that it also should insert it into the recipe_ingredients so I had to add `insertRecipeIngredients($link, $recipe_id, $ingredient_id, $unit, $amount, $i)($)` right after the insertIngredient function in the foreach loop*

---

I don't know if the title is exactly what I'm asking for but we'll see! I'm very new to all of this.. so please try to make the answers newbie-friendly (:

I have this foreach loop (sollution marked inside - - -):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($ingredients as $ingredient) {

    $ingredient_id = getIngredientId ($link, $ingredient);

    if($ingredient_id != false) {
        insertRecipeIngredient($link, $recipe_id, $ingredient_id, $unit, $amount, $i);
    } else {
        $ingredient_id = insertIngredient($link, $ingredient);
--- insertRecipeIngredient($link, $recipe_id, $ingredient_id, $unit, $amount, $i); ---
    }
    $i++;
}
```

and this code to insert into database:

```
function insertRecipeIngredient($link, $recipe_id, $ingredient_id, $unit, $amount, $i) {
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO recipe_ingredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id,
    unit, amount) VALUES ('$recipe_id','$ingredient_id', '$unit[$i]', '$amount[$i]')");
}
```

This works BUT it only inserts the first ingrediens in the array. Before I added the `$unit[$i]` and `$amount[$i]` it worked just fine. **(This was wrong, it only inserted the ingredients that was already in ingredient database and not the new ones)**

all of the variables comes from a form:

```
$unit = $_POST['unit'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
etc...
```

How am I suppose to get the rest of the arrays into the database?

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="form_process.php">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titel">
    <input type="text" name="portions" placeholder="Antal portioner">
    <div class="ingredient_wrap">
        <div class="first_ingredient">
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="instructions" placeholder="Beskrivning"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Skicka">
</form>
```

and this is the script for the amount/ingredient/unit thingy:

```
function createUnitSelect() {
    var units       = ['g', 'ml', 'dl'];
    var select      = "";

    $(units).each(function() {
        select = select + '<option value="'+this+'">'+this+'</option>';
    });

    return '<select name="unit[]">' + select + '</select>';
}

// All of the variables
var inputAmount     = '<input type="text" name="amount[]" placeholder="Mått">';
var inputUnit       = createUnitSelect();
var inputIngredient = '<input type="text" name="ingredient[]" placeholder="Ingrediens">';
var firstIngredient = $(".first_ingredient");
var wrapper         = $(".ingredient_wrap");
var buttonAdd       = '<button class="add_ingredient">+</button>';
var buttonRemove        = '<button class="remove_ingredient">-</button>';
var maxIngredients  = 20;
var x = 1;

// The first ingredient-row
$(inputAmount).appendTo(firstIngredient);
$(inputUnit).appendTo(firstIngredient);
$(inputIngredient).appendTo(firstIngredient);
$(buttonAdd).appendTo(firstIngredient);

// Button for adding ingredient and doing so
$(wrapper).on("click", ".add_ingredient", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < maxIngredients) {
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div>' + inputAmount + inputUnit + inputIngredient + buttonAdd + '</div>')   ;
    }

    $(this).removeClass("add_ingredient");
    $(this).addClass("remove_ingredient");
    $(this).text('-');

    return false;   
});

// Button for removing ingredient and doing so
$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_ingredient", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;

    return false;
});
```

when I do a `print_r($_POST)` i get:

Array ( [title] => meatballs [portions] => 4 [amount] => Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 2 [2] => 100 ) [unit] => Array ( [0] => g [1] => dl [2] => ml ) [ingredient] => Array ( [0] => meat [1] => unions [2] => tomatoes ) [instructions] => Mix and eat [submit] => Skicka )

This is how I get the recipe ID and the ingredient ID:

Recipe

```
// Insert the recipe
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO recipes (title, portions, instructions) VALUES ('$title', '$portions', '$instructions')") or die(mysqli_error());
$recipe_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

Ingredient

```
// Get id of ingredient in database if it exist
function getIngredientId ($link, $ingredient) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE ingredient='$ingredient'");

    if($result) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['id'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: r u using <input name="unit[]"> and <input name="amount[]">  ?? in HTML?

Comment: if you do `print_r($_POST)` what sort of resulting output do you get?

Comment: no just unit and amount without the [ ]

Comment: (side note: this code is vulnerable to SQL-injects, try using prepared statements instead)

Comment: There seems to be a lot of empty fields~ can you add your form to the question?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann is that when I use the ? instead of the '$variable'. I'm very new to this, started the course in january and it's very basic.

Comment: I've added some more, should I add the result from the `print_r($_POST)` too?

Comment: @RamRaider sorry, I forgot to put anything in the form before I made the print_r... I've added the output in the question.

Comment: there is an extra `)` in your `insertRecipeIngredient` function at the end ~ it should be within the sql statement rather than outside

Comment: @RamRaider sorry again, it's just how it looks here in the question (I'll change it) because in my file it's `...')")`

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of data posted to support your question ( it should be noted that embedding variables directly in the sql is a bad idea which can, and does, lead to sql injection attacks. The better approach would be to use prepared statements within `mysqli` or `pdo` )

```
/* 
    For testing, to emulate the submitted 
    form with data you provided. You, of course,
    have the actual $_POST data from the form to
    work with.
*/
$_POST=array ( 
    'title'         => 'meatballs',
    'portions'      => 4,
    'amount'        => array ( 100, 2, 100 ), 
    'unit'          => array('g','dl','ml'),
    'ingredient'    => array ('meat','unions','tomatoes'),
    'instructions'  => 'Mix and eat',
    'submit'        => 'Skicka'
);
define( 'BR','<br />' );



/* 
 Rather than a separate function to get the ingredient_id 
 you could use a subquery in the insert statement
*/
function insertRecipeIngredient( $link, $recipe_id, $ingredient, $amount, $unit ) {
    /* ensure that the ingredient is in the table. */
    $sql="insert ignore into `ingredients` set `ingredient`='{$ingredient}';";
    mysqli_query( $link, $sql );
    echo $sql.BR;

    $sql="insert into `recipe_ingredients` ( `recipe_id`, `ingredient_id`, `amount`, `unit` )
            values
            (   
                '{$recipe_id}',
                ( select `id` from `ingredients` where `ingredient`='{$ingredient}' ),
                '{$amount}',
                '{$unit}'
            );";
    mysqli_query( $link, $sql );
    echo $sql.BR;
}

/* get variables from POSTed data */
$title=$_POST['title'];
$portions=$_POST['portions'];
$amounts=$_POST['amount'];
$units=$_POST['unit'];
$ingredients=$_POST['ingredient'];
$instructions=$_POST['instructions'];


$sql="INSERT INTO `recipes` ( `title`, `portions`, `instructions` ) VALUES ( '$title', '$portions', '$instructions' );";
mysqli_query( $link, $sql ) or die( mysqli_error() );

$recipe_id = mysqli_insert_id( $link );

/* for debugging - comment out later */
echo $sql;

/*
    Assuming that each of the arrays 
    have the same number of elements
*/
foreach( $amounts as $i => $qty ){

    $ingredient=$ingredients[ $i ];
    $amount=$amounts[ $i ];
    $unit=$units[ $i ];

    call_user_func( 'insertRecipeIngredient', $link, $recipe_id, $ingredient, $amount, $unit );
}

/* which outputs the following */
INSERT INTO `recipes` ( `title`, `portions`, `instructions` ) VALUES ( 'meatballs', '4', 'Mix and eat' );
insert into `recipe_ingredients` ( `recipe_id`, `ingredient_id`, `amount`, `unit` ) values ( '3', ( select `id` from `ingredients` where `ingredient`='meat' ), '100', 'g' );
insert into `recipe_ingredients` ( `recipe_id`, `ingredient_id`, `amount`, `unit` ) values ( '3', ( select `id` from `ingredients` where `ingredient`='unions' ), '2', 'dl' );
insert into `recipe_ingredients` ( `recipe_id`, `ingredient_id`, `amount`, `unit` ) values ( '3', ( select `id` from `ingredients` where `ingredient`='tomatoes' ), '100', 'ml' );
```

The data is inserted correctly ( assuming the ingredients exist in the `ingredients` table first )

```
mysql> select * from recipes;
+----+-----------+----------+--------------+
| id | title     | portions | instructions |
+----+-----------+----------+--------------+
|  1 | meatballs |        4 | Mix and eat  |
+----+-----------+----------+--------------+

mysql> select * from recipe_ingredients;
+----+-----------+---------------+--------+------+
| id | recipe_id | ingredient_id | amount | unit |
+----+-----------+---------------+--------+------+
|  1 |         1 |             1 |    100 | g    |
|  2 |         1 |             2 |      2 | dl   |
|  3 |         1 |             3 |    100 | ml   |
+----+-----------+---------------+--------+------+

mysql> select * from ingredients;
+----+------------+
| id | ingredient |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Meat       |
|  2 | Onions     |
|  3 | Tomatoes   |
|  4 | Carrots    |
+----+------------+
```

Comment: yes `ingredient_id` is integers. my databases are: recipes (id, title, portions, instructions), ingredients (id, ingredient) and then the connection recipe_ingredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id, amount, unit).

Comment: I added information how I get the ingredient_id and the recipe_id in the question

Comment: `$stmt_recipe = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO recipes (title, portions, instructions) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt_recipe->bind_param("sss", $title, $portions, $instructions);
$stmt_recipe->execute() or die(mysqli_error());` is this the prepared statments? I'm new to this, but it seems to work. I'll try your example.

Comment: that is, as you say, a prepared statement and offers considerably better protection from sql injection that the methods above where unfiltered user supplied data is used directly in the sql

Comment: Good, then I learned something new, thank you! I found something interesting, read my edit in the very beginning.

Comment: any updates you'd care to share? has this now been resolved?

Comment: Yes, I manage to fix it this morning. And I didn't get your code to work, it was hard to integrate your code in my opinion, as I said I'm really new to this. BUT I'm happy because I did fix it by myself. The problem was the foreach loop. It only said that new ingredients should be inserted into the ingredient database and not in the recipe_ingredients, so I added some code there. I'll write it in the question

Comment: :( sorry you couldn't get it to work ~ works fine here.

Comment: But I did get it to work with my original code so it still works and I'm so happy for that! :D Next project is to manage to fix an input for pictures for the recipe, stored on the server I think our teacher said. So wish me luck and thank you for everything :)